# Why is there a py in windows and is there py in anaconda?

Tags: python, windows-10

Today I found this [article](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3617292/how-to-use-pythons-py-launcher-for-windows.html#:%7E:text=The%20py%20launcher%E2%80%94or%20just,%2Dbit%20or%2064%2Dbit.) in which it says there is something called a "Python launcher" called *py*.

I tried this today and I don't have any "py" probably because I use python by anaconda.

So, why is it necessary to have a "py" launcher in windows at all? And this does not exist in Anaconda, right? So we should just go straight and use "python" ?

Comment: have you worked with multiple python version in your system? have you worked in server environment where there is no UI only cli and need to use multiple python version with minimum dependency software  ie simple python not anaconda. so in that case it is useful

Comment: That is the beauty of anaconda, where each environment has its own python version...

Comment: anaconda is heavy and as i said minimum dependency :D

Comment: I see. How about miniconda?

Comment: well if it is easily workable and everyother person can use it easily then why not